# FTP List Command Response Structure Issue

Tags: ftp, filezilla

I've been beating my head against a wall on this issue so far. My server presently responds to the LIST -a command like this:

```
drwxr-xr-x 1 owner group          1 Feb 21 04:37 test
drwxr-xr-x 1 owner group     129024 Feb 21 11:05 tardis.mp3
```

For some reason, the second one is being parsed in Filezilla as a folder instead of a file. Long story short, it's not.  I know I'm missing something. Filezilla seems to not be able to see the file size.

Here's a screenshot:
[image: File listing screenshot]

Anyone have any thoughts on why Filezilla can't parse the file size? What am I missing?

Comment: could you post whole response code please?  filezilla is driving me crazy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second line in the listing *is* a directory. It has `d` in the first character of the permissions field. The size doesn't matter, directories have a size field too.

Comment: Ah HA!! OK. I'll have to take a look at the permissions line then.  I was unaware of the d being the directory marker. That helps me a lot.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, the `LIST` command output is meant for human reading and not for machine parsing. The output format is not standardised and as such not easy to parse. It might work for your particular case, but it might break if you change the FTP server software or change the locale.

As you mentioned FileZilla, you can have a look at the [FileZilla directory parser](http://svn.filezilla-project.org/filezilla/FileZilla3/trunk/src/engine/directorylistingparser.cpp?view=markup) for `LIST` command.

The best approach nowadays is to use the `MLSD` command for [Listings for Machine Processing](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3659#section-7) as the output format is well-defined and easy to parse.